# How to load the foreign keys elements in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

In my Django model, I have 10 fields and there are 3 fields which are foreign keys.
In my JSON data which is received from a GET request, I am getting all the fields but not the foreign keys.

I have also done this, but I am still not getting those fields in the JSON data:

```
DataFields = MyData._meta.get_all_field_names()
class MyResource(ModelResource):
       class Meta:
        queryset = MyData.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'Myres'
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        filtering = dict(zip(DataFields, [ALL_WITH_RELATIONS for f in DataFields]))
```

For example, I have the field in model like `city`, but that field is not available in the JSON I get from it.

Is there any way that in JSON I can get `city:city__name` automatically?

If I do this, then I get the city, but can I do that without defining:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data["city_name"] = bundle.obj.city__name
        return bundle
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to create [related resources](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-more-resources) for your foreign key fields and embed them in `MyResource`. If you make the embedded resource `full=True`, it'll dehydrate it when fetching `MyResource`, otherwise it'll embed it as the related resource uri.

```
class RelatedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        ...


class MyResource(ModelResource):
    related = fields.ForeignKey(RelatedResource, full=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
```

You can then filter by `?related__field=value` in the GET request to `MyResource`.

---

If you're just wanting the field returned by the model's `__unicode__`, you can try doing the following (rather than embedding a related resource):

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):    
    city = fields.CharField(attribute="city")

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Where "city" is the field name of the foreign key on the `MyData` model.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without defining any resource. Othwise i haave to make resource of my every model in djnago. isn't it time wastage

Comment: Making additional resources will be your best bet. You can create bare minimum resources, keep them off the API (don't add them to your URLs), and embed them with `full=True`. Won't be that much extra work. Otherwise, the dehydrate method is the alternative.