# How can i access the attribute of related model in tastypie in template

Tags: python, django, tastypie

When i get the JSON response then i get value like this

```
"objects": [
    {

        "created": "2012-11-01T10:25:25.019881",

        "district": {
            "created": "2012-10-31T05:48:36.883000",
            "description": "",
            "effective_from": "2012-10-31T05:48:36.882000",
            "effective_to": null,
            "id": 3,
            "modified": "2012-10-31T05:48:36.883000",

            "name": "bfdsfselt",
            "resource_uri": "",
            "slug": "fdfsf"
        },
        "effective_from": "2012-10-31T12:35:59.081232",
    }
]
```

I have the generic function which displays the value in the temple lie

```
for field in fields
    <td>obj[field] </td>
```

Now in my district field it display the whole json of district. is there any way that it only displays the name only. i have defined that in unicode but its not coming here.

Comment: Did we get this answered with your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301206/how-to-load-the-foreign-keys-elements-in-tasty-pie-djnago-python/13301739#13301739)?

Comment: @Blake i think don't so , but you can explain more.  i was not still able to get name from within district object in js template

Comment: I think you'd just need to go another step in your template for the district object and say something like: `obj["district"]["name"]`.